# What widget can I use to get this effect?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WktzElS5OxDboYdbGJH1J5LKaCqXDihi/view?usp=sharing

I would like to have a pinned image with a leading and an action and a widget that can be scrolled over the image and back again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be made with a [`DraggableScrollableSheet`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html), see the [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hgw819mL_78&ab_channel=Flutter) from the Flutter team.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CustomScrollView` and for the app bar, you can use `SliverAppBar` as a child.